# Count of days of each month from a list of dates python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

How can I count the number of days of each month for current year from a list of dates in *python*. Consider I have a date list as:

```
10/Mar/2016 06:39:31
16/Nov/2015 06:16:27
16/Dec/2012 06:39:31
16/Dec/2015 06:16:27
9/Mar/2016 06:16:27
15/Nov/2015 06:16:27
15/Mar/2012 06:39:31
15/Nov/2015 06:16:27
15/Sep/2015 06:16:27
15/Jan/2015 06:16:27
16/Feb/2016 06:16:27
16/Jan/2016 06:39:31
16/Feb/2016 06:39:31
15/Feb/2012 06:16:27
12/Mar/2016 06:16:27
16/Nov/2012 06:16:27
8/Jan/2016 06:16:27
10/Mar/2016 06:39:31
16/Nov/2012 06:39:31
16/Nov/2012 06:16:20
7/Mar/2016 06:16:27
15/Nov/2012 06:16:27
16/Jan/2016 06:16:27
16/Oct/2015 06:39:31
```

Now I want `Jan-3` , `Feb-2`, `Mar-5` and so on.

I tried

```
from datetime import datetime as date_for_conv
if(times> date_for_conv.strptime(times, "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("2016/Jan/%d")):
    jan+=1
```

`times` is the list element iterated in a loop. This gives the count for Jan month only, I want to do it in a single condition check. What should I do?

Comment: because there is no date for 2016-Mar

Comment: Sorry, there are few entries.

Comment: why is the down vote for?

Comment: I can see two dates in March 2016 - fourth and seventh from the bottom of the list.

Comment: 10/Mar/2016, 9/Mar/2016, 12/Mar/2016, 7/Mar/2016, no date for 2016-Mar? please re-edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to count is to use a dictionary. Add new keys and increment if it exists:

```
from datetime import datetime
times = ['10/Mar/2016 06:39:31','16/Nov/2015 06:16:27','16/Dec/2012 06:39:31','16/Dec/2015 06:16:27',
         '9/Mar/2016 06:16:27','15/Nov/2015 06:16:27','15/Mar/2012 06:39:31','15/Nov/2015 06:16:27',
         '15/Sep/2015 06:16:27','15/Jan/2015 06:16:27','16/Feb/2016 06:16:27','16/Jan/2016 06:39:31',
         '16/Feb/2016 06:39:31','15/Feb/2012 06:16:27','12/Mar/2016 06:16:27','16/Nov/2012 06:16:27',
         '8/Jan/2016 06:16:27','10/Mar/2016 06:39:31','16/Nov/2012 06:39:31','16/Nov/2012 06:16:20',
         '7/Mar/2016 06:16:27','15/Nov/2012 06:16:27','16/Jan/2016 06:16:27','16/Oct/2015 06:39:31']

counters = {}
for t in times:
    month = datetime.strptime(t, "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime('%b')
    if month in counters:
        counters[month] += 1
    else:
        counters[month] = 1

for k,v in counters.items():
    print('{}-{}'.format(k,v))
```

This returns:

```
Oct-1
Dec-2
Mar-6
Jan-4
Feb-3
Sep-1
Nov-7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Exactly what I was looking for. You saved a lot of time... Thanks once again !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in data.txt, this does it in a fairly efficient manner (without reading everything into memory and sorting it). I have somewhat of a fascination lately with itertools and collections, mostly because they tend to make things a LOT faster, but it is also more pythonic. Consulting the documentation on how they work is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
from itertools import imap
from collections import defaultdict

counters = defaultdict(int)
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    lines = iter(fp.readline, '')
    mos = imap(lambda s: s.split('/')[1], lines)
    for mo in mos:
        counters[mo] += 1

for m, c in counters.items():
    print "{}: {}".format(m, c)
```

Edit: I realise that you also have the requirement that if there are no dates for a month, then you want those listed too. For that, you could import the `calendar` module, but you're going to run into issues with locales. So it might be best to simply loop through all 12 months:

```
for m in ('Jan', 'Feb', ...):
    print "{}: {}".format(m, counters.get(m, 0))
```

Comment: Actually I had a text file, but along with dates there are other contents too. If it had only dates, I could have done it your way. But I am referring your answer too for solution. Trying to implement using dictionary and counters.